# Matching randomly generated number to object properties

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a random number generator with max, min shown below, is it possible to identify if a object property (int ID in my case) matches the random number generated?
Or is there another way that I can 'Randomly' pick an object from a collection?

Random number generator is:

```
private readonly Random _random = new Random();
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
   return _random.Next(min, max);
}
```

And I am looking to pick from an object located in a collection such as:

```
public class Staff
{
     public int ID;
     public Staff(int ID)
     {
         ID = this.ID
     }
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         List<Staff> StaffList = new List<Staff>();
         StaffList.Add(new Staff(6);
     }
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to fix your constructor, you got the assignment backwards

```
    public Staff(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
```

This is how you get a random item from a list:

```
var randomStaffItem = StaffList[RandomNumber(0, StaffList.Count)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Lev gave an excellent answer on picking a random `Staff` instance from your List.

You also asked:

> ... is it possible to identify if a object property (int ID in my
> case) matches the random number generated?

You can use [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) to determine if the ID exists.  If you need the actual matching instance, then you could use [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1) instead.  They both receive a [predicate in the form of a lamba expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Examples of using both `Any()` and `FirstOrDefault()` below:

```
class Program
{

    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        return _random.Next(min, max);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Staff> StaffList = new List<Staff>();
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            StaffList.Add(new Staff(i));
        }

        int rndID = RandomNumber(1, 21); // 1 to 20 inclusive
        Console.WriteLine("Random ID: " + rndID.ToString());

        var StaffExists = StaffList.Any(s => s.ID == rndID);
        if (StaffExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There does exist a staff member with an ID of " + rndID.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There does NOT exist a staff member with an ID of " + rndID.ToString());
        }

        var StaffMatch = StaffList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == rndID);
        if (StaffMatch != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found: " + StaffMatch.ID.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No match found.");
        }

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```